# I ran smartctl to see my hard disk health and I got this much error should I need to be worry?

Tags: smartctl

I ran smartctl to see my hard disk health andI got this log for a 2TB hard disk. Is having this much error normal thing ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't include screen shots. You can use copy-and-paste from the terminal to include the text. Indent four spaces to keep the formatting.

To interpret smartctl values, you need to know that they are normalized to 100, and less is worse.

You have a significant raw read error rate and a significant seek error rate.

So yes, you should worry. Make a backup of all valuable data; and don't use this disk to store anything on it you don't want to loose.